abelian differentials are $L^2$ integrable
Let $C$ be a smooth algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ (we can think for instance of a compact Riemann surface). Let $A$ be the subset of classes of holomorphic forms $\omega$ in $H^1(C,\mathbb{C})$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{X}\omega\wedge\overline{\omega} <\infty
\end{equation}

Why is $A=H^{1,0}(C,\mathbb{C})$?

The inclusion $A\subset H^{1,0}(C,\mathbb{Z})$ is obvious, but if $C$ is smooth, does it imply that any $(1,0)$ holomorphic form is $L^2$ integrable?
Thank you for any help or reference.

Yes. Pick a smooth volume form $dV$ on $C$ (or just a Hermitian metric). Then $\omega \wedge \bar \omega = f , dV$ for a smooth function $f$ on $C$ and that is integrable by compactness.

Thank you! Is there any reference where I can read about it? especially the fact that $\omega \wedge \bar \omega = f , dV$?
I will happily accept your comment if you write it as an answer.

I think you can look at Chapter 1.2 in Huybrecht's "Complex geometry". In general picking a Hermitian metric on a manifold gives inner products on $(p,q)$-forms. Since holomorphic $p$-forms are in particular primitive, the inner product of two top-degree holomorphic forms is (up to a constant) just the wedge of one form with the conjugate of the other.

Thank you for the reference and explanation!
